# Nodejs Mysql Query Chaining

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I want to write following queries

```
Select id from table1
```

Use that resultset of id  and

```
Select * from table2 where id in (resultset)
```

How can I implement it using Nodejs and MySQL. I am beginner to Nodejs express framework.

Answer (score 0):

You could use string concatenation:

```
const query1 = "Select id from table1";

const query2 = `Select * from table2 where id in (${query1})`
```

or just write the nested query:

```
const query = "Select * from table2 where id in (Select id from table1)"
```